# Kotlin arrow shortcut/hot key

Tags: android, kotlin

Is there any build in hot key/auto completion for "arrow", or "arrow with brackets"
`->`
`->{}`

Writing this constructs kind of annoying, especially with the location of the keys.

Comment: No. But you can create a live template in Android Studio. Go to `File` -> `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `Live Template`